# Comparing two unordered lists of objects based on a closure

Tags: java, list, groovy

I have two unordered lists. What I want to do is compare these two lists based on some conditions that I can specify through a closure/ pointer function.

What I am having problem is the structure of objects in these lists may be different and I want to compare some attributes in some cases but other attributes in other case.

e.g.

```
Class sampleObj{
    String attribute1;
    List attribute2;
    String attribute3;
}

List A
 Obj1-> attribute1 = "test",attribute2 = ["a","b","c"]
 Obj2 -> attribute1 = "optionalArg test 2",attribute3 = "optionalArg"

List B
Obj1 -> attribute3 = "test4", attribute2 = [1,2,3]
Obj2 -> attribute3 = "optionalArg"
Obj3 -> attribute1 = "test",attribute2 = ["a","b","c"]
```

In this case Object 1 in List A is equal to Object 3 in List B (both the required attributes of object are equal) and object 2 in list A is equal to Object 2 in List B (The value of attribute 3 is a substring of attribute 1).

So, my condition could be based on a cross product of attribute 1 and attribute 2 or on attribute 3.
Meaning if attribute1 and attribute2 are equal for object 1 from ListA and object 3 from ListB, we can say that these two objects are equal, Otherwise if attribute 3 matches some condition for attribute 1 then we can say the objects are equal meaning object 2 from listB can be equal to object2 from list A (condition being substring check in this case)

In general I am trying to write this library method that would take two lists and a closure and then based on the closure passed lets me know whether some objects in list A match list B or vice-versa.

Let me know if there are any questions/clarifications needed here or/and if you can guide me in the right direction.

Comment: this description really does not tell us enough about your success criteria. I cannot tell from your description whether your two sample lists match each other or not. Could you take some time in your description to give some sample matches and match failures and explain why they succeed or fail? Or maybe you could show us some sample code of what you have tried that didn't work?

Comment: Please respond, @Mayank

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. So, the basic thing I want to do is compare two list of objects and sending the logic for comparison as a pointer function/Comparable/Closure etc. The objects in list do not have to be of the same type but may have some common properties.

Comment: After the method is executed, the method should give me objects that do not match the comparison criteria. I am able to do it if the objects in list are of same type but having problem when objects aren't of same type.

Comment: your abstract elaboration of your previous abstract explanation was not helpful. Please provide some examples.

Comment: I have edited the initial question to make it more clear. I hope it makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to know is whether or not matches exist between two lists according to arbitrary criteria then all you need is the following:

```
def hasMatches(List a, List b, Closure<Boolean> matchCriteria) {
  a && b && a.any{ aa -> b.any { bb -> matchCriteria(aa, bb) || matchCriteria(bb, aa) } }
}
```

Then the following assertions all return true:

```
class SampleObj{
  String attribute1
  List attribute2
  String attribute3
  String name

  @Override String toString() { name }
}

List<SampleObj> listA = [
    [name: "ObjA1", attribute1: "test", attribute2: ["a","b","c"]] as SampleObj,
    [name: "ObjA2", attribute1: "optionalArg test 2", attribute3: "optionalArg"] as SampleObj
]

List<SampleObj> listB = [
    [name: "ObjB1", attribute3: "test4", attribute2: [1,2,3]] as SampleObj,
    [name: "ObjB2", attribute3: "optionalArg"] as SampleObj,
    [name: "ObjB3", attribute1: "test", attribute2: ["a","b","c"]] as SampleObj
]

// there exists at least one object in list A whose attribute 1 value matches that of at least one object in list B (or vice versa)
assert hasMatches(listA, listB) { SampleObj aa, SampleObj bb -> aa?.attribute1 == bb?.attribute1 }

// there exists at least one object in list B whose attribute 3 value is a substring of the attribute 1 value of at least one object in list A (or vice versa)
assert hasMatches(listA, listB) { SampleObj aa, SampleObj bb -> bb?.attribute3 && aa?.attribute1?.contains(bb.attribute3) }

// there does not exist any object in list A whose attribute 1 value is contained in the attribute 2 list of any object in list B (or vice versa)
assert !hasMatches(listA, listB) { SampleObj aa, SampleObj bb -> aa?.attribute1 && bb?.attribute2?.contains(aa.attribute1) }
```

If, on the other hand, you actually want to see the matching pairs, then you need something a bit more extensive:

```
def findEquivalentPairs(List a, List b, Closure<Boolean> matchCriteria) {
  a && b \
    ? a.sum { aa ->
      def ab = b.findResults { bb -> matchCriteria(aa, bb) ? [aa, bb] : null } ?: []
      def ba = b.findResults { bb -> matchCriteria(bb, aa) ? [bb, aa] : null } ?: []
      ab + ba
    }
    : []
}
```

Then, printing out the results using the same three criteria closures...

```
println findEquivalentPairs(listA, listB) { SampleObj aa, SampleObj bb -> aa?.attribute1 == bb?.attribute1 }
println findEquivalentPairs(listA, listB) { SampleObj aa, SampleObj bb -> bb?.attribute3 && aa?.attribute1?.contains(bb.attribute3) }
println findEquivalentPairs(listA, listB) { SampleObj aa, SampleObj bb -> aa?.attribute1 && bb?.attribute2?.contains(aa.attribute1) }
```

... yields the following:

```
[[ObjA1, ObjB3], [ObjB3, ObjA1]]
[[ObjA2, ObjB2]]
[]
```

Comment: This looks exactly like what I was going for. I will try it later today to check with my particular use case.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would use a [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) to achieve this.

The `Comparable` interface defines a `compareTo()` function, which you can implement to achieve whatever comparison logic you require.

Or, simply override the `equals()` method.

Comment: @Mayank seems to be talking about some sort of equivalence class matching comparison, not an ordering comparison. Furthermore, I think the comparison logic itself is what is stymieing him/her. Your answer reminds me of the old Steve Martin joke about how to be a millionaire and never pay taxes: "First, get a million dollars. Then..." :-)

Comment: Well, it's not like `Comparable` is some exotic, obscure mechanism.  It's well-known, well documented and easily understood, if the OP chooses to do some basic investigation.

Comment: Right, so what makes you think that this is the answer he is looking for? It sounds to me more like he/she is having trouble with the programming logic itself and how to express it in a Groovy closure ( I only assume the latter since closures are mentioned in the title).

Comment: Feel free to post an answer.

Comment: I probably will, if he/she ever gets around to answering my clarification questions.

Comment: It's been 23 hours since he's visited.  Hope you have the time to wait.